# How to display the duplicate phone number from call log ,contact list and inbox in android

Tags: android, listview, duplicates, phone-number, calllog

I want to retrieve the phone number from the call log, contact list and inbox to compare that number to a list and display it only once in a  `listview`.

I'm able to get contacts from call log, contact list and inbox but the problem is that I'm not able to compare the number from call log and the contact list because they are stored in a different format.

My question is how can I compare both numbers regardless of their formating?

Current code is as follows:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   TextView textView = null;
   ArrayList<String> call_log_no;
   ArrayList<String> call_log_name;
   String strStatus = "";
  public boolean[] status;
  StringBuffer sb;
  String phNum,cname,details;
  MatrixCursor mMatrixCursor;
  ArrayList<String> choiceList;
  ListView lvCountries;
  HashMap<String,Object> hm;
  int pos;

List<HashMap<String,Object>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

 /** Restore from the previous state if exists */
 if(savedInstanceState!=null){
  status = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray("status");
}



 call_log_no = new ArrayList<String>();
 call_log_name = new ArrayList<String>();
 choiceList = new ArrayList<String>();



  lvCountries = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);


  OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lv, View item, int position, long   id) {

      ListView lView = (ListView) lv;

      SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) lView.getAdapter();

      HashMap<String,Object> hm = (HashMap) adapter.getItem(position);

       /** The clicked Item in the ListView */
      RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) item;

      /** Getting the toggle button corresponding to the clicked item */
     ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton) rLayout.getChildAt(0);


      String strStatus = "";
      if(tgl.isChecked()){
          tgl.setChecked(false);
          strStatus = "Off";
          status[position]=false;
      }else{
          tgl.setChecked(true);
          strStatus = "On";
          status[position]=true;
      }
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), (String) hm.get("no") + " : " + strStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  };

 lvCountries.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

    // Each row in the list stores country name and its status
  List<HashMap<String,Object>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();


 // The contacts from the contacts content provider is stored in this cursor
 mMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id","name","details"} );

 getCallDetails();

     //Creating an AsyncTask object to retrieve and load listview with contacts
     ListViewContactsLoader listViewContactsLoader = new           ListViewContactsLoader();

// Starting the AsyncTask process to retrieve and load listview with contacts
 listViewContactsLoader.execute();

 }

   /** An AsyncTask class to retrieve and load listview with contacts */
  private class ListViewContactsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor>     {

 @Override
 protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
     Uri contactsUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

     // Querying the table ContactsContract.Contacts to retrieve all the contacts
     Cursor contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(contactsUri, null, null, null,
     ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");

     if(contactsCursor.moveToFirst()){
         do{
             long contactId = contactsCursor.getLong(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));

             Uri dataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

             // Querying the table ContactsContract.Data to retrieve individual items like
             // home phone, mobile phone, work email etc corresponding to each contact
             Cursor dataCursor = getContentResolver().query(dataUri, null,
                                 ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId,
                                 null, null);

             String displayName="";

             String homePhone="";
             String mobilePhone="";
             String workPhone="";

             if(dataCursor.moveToFirst()){
                 // Getting Display Name
                 displayName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME ));
                 do{

                     // Getting NickName

                  // Getting Phone numbers
                     if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                         switch(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))){
                             case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME :
                                 homePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                 boolean isStringExists = (call_log_no.contains(homePhone)||(call_log_no.contains("+91"+homePhone)));
                                 if(isStringExists==true)
                                 {

                                 }

                                 else{
                                     call_log_no.add(homePhone);
                                     call_log_name.add(displayName);

                                 }

                                 break;
                             case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE :
                                 mobilePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));

                                 mobilePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                 boolean isStringE = (call_log_no.contains(mobilePhone)||(call_log_no.contains("+91"+mobilePhone)));
                                 if(isStringE==true)
                                 {

                                 }

                                 else{
                                     call_log_no.add(mobilePhone);
                                     call_log_name.add(displayName);

                                 }

                                 break;
                             case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK :
                                 workPhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                 boolean isStringExis = (call_log_no.contains(workPhone)||(call_log_no.contains("+91"+workPhone)));
                                 if(isStringExis==true)
                                 {

                                 }

                                 else{
                                     call_log_no.add(workPhone);
                                     call_log_name.add(displayName);

                                 }
                                 break;
                         }
                     }








                 }while(dataCursor.moveToNext());
                 String details = "";


                 // Adding id, display name, path to photo and other details to cursor
                 mMatrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{ Long.toString(contactId),displayName,details});
             }
         }while(contactsCursor.moveToNext());
     }
     return mMatrixCursor;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
     status = new boolean[call_log_name.size()];

    for(int i = 0,j = 0,k=0; i < call_log_name.size() ; i++,j++,k++)
      {
          HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String,Object>();
          status[k]=false;
        // choiceList.add("\nName: "+call_log_name.get(i)+"\nPhone Number: " + call_log_no.get(j));
         hm.put("no", call_log_no.get(i));
         hm.put("txt", call_log_name.get(j));
         hm.put("stat",status[k]);
         aList.add(hm);


      }


     // Keys used in Hashmap
     String[] from = {"txt","no","stat" };

     // Ids of views in listview_layout
     int[] to = {R.id.tv_item,R.id.tv_no, R.id.tgl_status};

     // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
     // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
     SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.activity_main, from, to);



     lvCountries.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
  }



private void getCallDetails() {

String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
/* Query the CallLog Content Provider */
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
 null, null, strOrder);
 int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
  int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
 int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
 int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
 int name= managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);

 while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
 phNum = managedCursor.getString(number);
 String callTypeCode = managedCursor.getString(type);
 String strcallDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
 Date callDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(strcallDate));
  String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
 cname=managedCursor.getString(name);
 String callType = null;
 int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);
 switch (callcode) {
   case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
        callType = "Outgoing";
        break;
  case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
       callType = "Incoming";
      break;
 case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
      callType = "Missed";
      break;
 }

  boolean isStringExists = (call_log_no.contains(phNum)|| (call_log_no.contains("+91"+phNum)));
 if(isStringExists==true)
 {

    }
  else{
   call_log_no.add(phNum);
   call_log_name.add(cname);
    } }
   managedCursor.close();
       }

    @Override
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   outState.putBooleanArray("status", status);
     } 
   }
```

please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using the following library [libphoneNumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

which has a method called isNumberMatch which takes into consideration the country code. example :

```
 PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

 PhoneNumberUtil.MatchType match = phoneUtil.isNumberMatch(firstNumber, secondNumber);

 if(match.name().equals("NSN_MATCH")){
     //Its a match!
 }
```

Comment: i am saving contacts in  arraylist so how i can use that

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: i am retriving data from phone contact database

Comment: ok..you have to loop through all numbers in the contacts list..may you can narrow the search by using substring by at least 5 characters : number.substring(Math.max(number.length() - 5, 0), number.length()); , then using contactscontract to query the numbers